# Eval function is C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help in understanding what the Eval bit does (Just started learning C#.net):

```
<asp:Image 
 ID="Image1" 
 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "~/UploadImages/{0} %>'
 ...
```

The image is in a datalist repeater which has been binded to a folder containing images files.

I'm confused with the "Name" and {0}.. what is the significance of these and in what situation can I change them.

Comment: Is the property 'Name', the default property type for data from .GetFiles() ? These property types are default properties that are fixed (not set)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eval statement in an aspx or ascx file is usually used to dynamically evaluate a binding statement within the context of the item bound to the current row in a databound control.

The first parameter is the property/field to bind to on the row.  The second parameter is an *optional* format string.  {0} will be replace with the value of the Name property in rendering the output text.

Here's the relevant [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval.aspx). Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

That is a format string.  Whatever is evaluated by the property, call it evalResult, of the first parameter to eval is passed through a `String.Format("~/UploadImages/{0}", evalResult)`

So, if the value in your dataset field for name is "Steve.jpg", your grid will show:
`<img src="/UploadImages/Steve.jpg" ... />`

For more information on Eval, check out msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the content of "Name" will be inserted in the placeholder {0}.

This way if you have

```
Name = "ImageName"
```

Your ImageUrl will be

```
ImageUrl="~/UploadImages/ImageName"
```

This is useful in dynamic cenarios because for each object the repeater will change the Name property accordingly to form the image URL.